# Rotating an element back and forth

Tags: javascript, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an element back and forth after 1 second, the code returns an error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" instead of rotating back. What can I do to achieve the aforementioned? Also what does this error message actually mean?

```
var rotated = false;

function clicked() {
    document.getElementById('box').onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('box'),
        deg = rotated ? 0 : 22;

    div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    div.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    div.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    div.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    div.style.transform       = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
  }
 setTimeout(reset, 1000);
function reset() {
     reset();
    }
  }
function reset() {
    document.getElementById('box').onclick = function() {
     var div = document.getElementById('box'),
        deg = rotated ? 0 : -22;

    div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    div.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    div.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    div.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    div.style.transform       = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
  }
}


         body{
    background-color:#ccc;
    }    
     #cont{
        width:90%;
        height:104%;
        background-color:white;
        position:absolute;
        left:65px;
        top:-30px;
    }
    #box{
      background-color:black;
      width:15%;
      height:24.6%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      position:absolute;
      top:35.7%;
       left:41.7%;
   }
```

Comment: You have a function called `reset()` which seems to call itself indefinitely.  This would blow out the stack if you ever call that function.  (I also see a second function called `reset()`, so you probably just need to give them different names to resolve this).

Comment: Thanks, but it still isnt calling to second funciton correcty

Comment: Did you update the name of the second `reset()` function and also update the name of the function that is called from within the first `reset()` function?

Comment: Also, you refer to the `reset()` function in `setTimeout(reset, 1000)` before you've actually declared the `reset()` function.  I'm not sure about Javascript, but most languages would not do what you want.  Try defining the function before calling `setTimeout`.

Comment: So I got it to call the function, but the second function itself isn't working. Do you know how I could get the second function to return the 22' rotation back to 0'?